# GoAccess won't redirect its output as a CGI script

Tags: bash, io-redirection, apache-httpd, cgi

I've been pulling my hair with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Content-type: text/html
echo ""
goaccess -f /var/www/log/access.log -a | tee
```

Which runs perfectly on the command line (generates HTML output for access.log), but when I run it as a CGI via the URL, the output isn't the HTML I'm expecting from GoAccess web analyzer but rather:

```
GoAccess - 0.7 

Usage: goaccess -f log_file [-c][-r][-m][-h][-q][-d][...]

The following options can also be supplied to the command: 
       -f - Path to input log file.
<snipped>
```

It is as if it's running `goaccess` without any parameters. Either that, or the parameters I specify in my Bash CGI aren't being seen for whatever reason.

I'm at the end of my wits. Any people w/some CGI experience that can help?

Comment: If brm's answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it as the answer with the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, if you use `-f` to specify the log file a check is done to see if stdin is an interactive tty and if not, the program exists. From goaccess.c (line 792 for version 0.7):

```
if (conf.ifile != NULL && !isatty (STDIN_FILENO))
    cmd_help ();
```

Using `cat` to send the log file through a pipe does work, but I also needed to specify where a config file could be found:

```
cat /var/www/log/access.log | goaccess -p /home/brm/.goaccessrc -a
```